# Can a binomial be a term?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, definition, problem-solving, regular-expressions

This is probably a silly question but I'll ask anyway. I know that terms in mathematics are numbers or variables or some combination of numbers/variables multiplied by each other. They are combined through addition and subtraction. So, in the expression $3a + 2b - 4$, $3a$ is a term, $2b$ is a term and $4$ is a term. But what about an expression or an equation where a binomial (or trinomial, etc.) is embedded within a product or a rational expression? So, for instance–in the expression

$$2x(x+1) + 4x^2 - 2x$$

Is $x + 1$ considered a term? Do we consider $2x(x+1)$ a term? Or would I just say $2x$, $x$, $1$, $4x^2$ and $2x$ are terms? Please help to clarify!

Comment: The answer to this question is "It doesn't matter, just make it a point to communicate your meaning clearly in context"

Comment: This is sort-of a weird question because it's not about the polynomial, it's about the _way we refer_ to the polynomial. So I think the main people who would care about this would be logicians, since they're the ones most interested in the relation between symbol and referent

Comment: Use the definition of "term" in your textbook.  Not all books agree on the definition.  And (after the beginner stage), neither will you.

Comment: It's nothing universal, but I tend to think of the terms in an expression being the things at the top level, so in $2x(x+1) + 4x^2 - 2x$ there are three terms, $2x(x+1)$, $4x^2$, and $ - 2x$. And in the expression $2x(x+1)$ there are also three terms, $2$,$x$, and $(x+1)$. But if someone is going to be grading you on this, ask them for their definition.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC I would say that in the expression $2x(x+1)$ there are three *factors* which are $2$, $x$, and $(x+1)$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov - So they are only "terms" when it's addition? I could see that. How many terms would you say there are in $\frac{2x+1}{3x+1}$?

Comment: I agree with Misha Lavrov.  $\frac{2x + 1}{3x + 1}$ has a numerator and a denominator; it would be very odd for someone to speak of it as having terms.  (The numerator and denominator each of two terms, though.)